# Programmatically dumping list of SubjectAltNames contained within file

Tags: python-3.x

I am ultimately trying to provide my program with a file that contains lines of hosts - each on their own line. The file looks something like this:

```
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
www.domain3.com
```

I want the program to take each individual line and extract the "SubjectAltName".

My non-working code looks like this:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl as reqs
def https_cert_subject_alt_names(host, port):
x509 = reqs.OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(
reqs.OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,
reqs.ssl.get_server_certificate((host, port))
)
return reqs.get_subj_alt_name(x509)
if __name__ == '__main__':
x = open('hosts.txt')
for line in x.readlines():
domains = https_cert_subject_alt_names(line, 443)
print(domains)
x.close()
```

I have partial success when removing the for/loops and just specifying the domain directly with the code. So, I at least know that the basic idea is solid.

The working code looks like this:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl as reqs
def https_cert_subject_alt_names(host, port):
x509 = reqs.OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(
reqs.OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,
reqs.ssl.get_server_certificate((host, port))
)
return reqs.get_subj_alt_name(x509)
if __name__ == '__main__':
domains = https_cert_subject_alt_names("www.google.com", 443)
print(domains)
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> ```
> for line in x.readlines():
>     domains = https_cert_subject_alt_names(line, 443)
> ```

`readlines` will return line endings, e.g. newline or CRLF.
It appears `https_cert_subject_alt_names` wants to see just a hostname,
without extraneous whitespace.

Phrase it like this, using **rstrip**:

```
for host in x.readlines():
    domains = https_cert_subject_alt_names(host.rstrip(), 443)
    print(domains)
```